# use SSO to authenticate users for network drive

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

My web application uses SSO authentication through Azure AD. From within my application, the user can access a network folder by providing required credentials. I would like to use the same SSO authentication that was done at login instead of manually entering the credentials to access the network folder. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same token because Azure AD will Authorize only for initial login.
If you want to use the SSO solution for your network folder access which is accessed inside your web application, you need to create a new instance for your network folder access.
Ultimately you need to create two instances in Azure AD for your application to get the token to access both application sign in and network folder access with single set of credential.
You can create a new application with different name.
Now you no need to enter the credential twice in your application (SSO happen).